# Unable to start/create SQLite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I was working with a database table containing a player's name, number of victories and number of losses.
Then I would call the database from the main activity, open, update or whatever and finally, close.

And that was working just fine.

Then I added the other columns and kept working.
However, I installed the game onto a real device and it didn't work.
The problem wasn't happening in my emulator as it was kinda overwritting the existing database again and again.
I decided to unistall the app from the emulator and then stopped working too.   It seems like my game had found some trouble in creating a new database when first started.

After doing some tests, I got different errors like "not null constrain" or "CursorIndexOutOfBounds".
Therefore, I could say that the problem is in the creation of the database - but I have no idea of what's wrong.
I don't think that the error is in the main Activity, as I've done always the same there and it used to work before, but I've changed the database.

Maybe the problem is where I initialize the values in the `onCreate()` function, like it's not really giving values to the database?

Anyway, maybe I've been focusing on the wrong point, so I thought that new perspectives might help.

Here you have the database class:

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {

private final Context context;

public static final String C_COLUMNA_ID   = "_id";
public static final String C_COLUMNA_NAME = "menu_player";
public static final String C_COLUMNA_VICTORY = "menu_victory";
public static final String C_COLUMNA_LOSS = "menu_loss";
public static final String C_COLUMNA_POINTS = "menu_points";
public static final String C_COLUMNA_UNLOCKED = "menu_unlocked";
public static final String C_COLUMNA_LEVEL = "menu_level";

private static final String NAME_TABLE = "menu";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
private String INSERT_OR_UPDATE_RECORD;

private DatabaseHelper DatabaseHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DatabaseAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    DatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database){
        database.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE MENU(" +
                " _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                " menu_player TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                " menu_victory INTEGER, " +
                " menu_loss INTEGER," +
                " menu_points INTEGER," +
                " menu_unlocked INTEGER," +
                " menu_level INTEGER)");

        //initialize
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO MENU(_id, menu_player) VALUES(1,'Pla Yer Uan')");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO MENU(_id, menu_victory) VALUES(1,0)");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO MENU(_id, menu_loss) VALUES(1,0)");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO MENU(_id, menu_points) VALUES(1,0)");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO MENU(_id, menu_unlocked) VALUES(1,0)");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO MENU(_id, menu_level) VALUES(1,1)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS todo");
        onCreate(database);
    }

}

public DatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException{
    db = DatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    DatabaseHelper.close();
}

public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, String columna, String newPlayerName, int value){
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    switch (columna){
        case "nombre":
            args.put(C_COLUMNA_NOMBRE, newPlayerName);
            break;
        case "victory":
            args.put(C_COLUMNA_VICTORY,value);
            break;
        case "loss":
            args.put(C_COLUMNA_LOSS,value);
            break;
        case "royals":
            args.put(C_COLUMNA_POINTS,value);
            break;
        case "unlocked":
            args.put(C_COLUMNA_UNLOCKED,value);
            break;
        case "level":
            args.put(C_COLUMNA_LEVEL,value);
            break;
    }

    return db.update(NAME_TABLE,args,C_COLUMNA_ID + "=" + rowId,null)>0;
}

public void backToDefault(){
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(C_COLUMNA_NAME, "Pla Yer Uan");
    args.put(C_COLUMNA_VICTORIAS,0);
    args.put(C_COLUMNA_DERROTAS,0);
    args.put(C_COLUMNA_ROYALS,0);
    args.put(C_COLUMNA_UNLOCKED,0);
    args.put(C_COLUMNA_LEVEL,1);
    db.update(NAME_TABLE,args,C_COLUMNA_ID + "=" + 1,null);
}

public Cursor getRecord(long rowId, String columna) throws SQLException{
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, NAME_TABLE, new String[]{
            C_COLUMNA_ID,
            columna
            },
            C_COLUMNA_ID + "=" + rowId,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    if (cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}

}
```

Getting this error:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Comment: You are inserting same primary key multiple times in onCreate Method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
    //initialize
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO MENU(_id, menu_player) VALUES(1,'Pla Yer Uan')");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO MENU(_id, menu_victory) VALUES(1,0)");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO MENU(_id, menu_loss) VALUES(1,0)");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO MENU(_id, menu_points) VALUES(1,0)");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO MENU(_id, menu_unlocked) VALUES(1,0)");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO MENU(_id, menu_level) VALUES(1,1)");
```

is really wrong

You must insert a full row **at once**, like so:

```
    //initialize
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO MENU(menu_player, menu_victory, menu_loss, menu_points, menu_unlocked, menu_level) VALUES('Pla Yer Uan', 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)");
```

Also notice that you don't have to insert the `_id` field, since it's an autoincrement primary key

Comment: It's the first time I work with a database, I'm trying to learn while doing this too...

I changed what you commented but I still get the error.

Comment: I'm asking for the first row which is supposed to be there after fixing the `database.execSQL("INSERT INTO MENU(menu_player, menu_victory, menu_loss, menu_points, menu_unlocked, menu_level) VALUES('Pla Yer Uan', 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)");` right? Also I didn't set an autoincrement primary key, I just work with one row multiple columns.

Comment: You are getting this error because the cursor returned no rows at all. Which means you are passing a non existing `rowID` to `public Cursor getRecord(long rowId, String columna)`. Don't rely on that an `_id` column is always starting at **0**. Because, if you deleted the previous rows, the `_id` counter is **not zeroed**.

Comment: `I didn't set an autoincrement primary key` Then, what is this `database.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE MENU(" +
                " _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"`?

Comment: But I didn't use the keyword autoincrement, shouldn't that allow me to reuse the rowId? So then I can just update that row?

Comment: NO. "AUTOINCREMENT" is optional and it's automatically inserted on primary key fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98485/discussion-between-josepmeg-and-frank-n-stein).

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone, changes in the database caused incompatibilities with the previous installed database. So going to the emulator and uninstalling the app and installing it again (once some changes are made) might also help.